# PHP - How to print string with specifict pattern ? (Word Search Grid)

Tags: php

I need help to print a string with specific words. It's kinda words puzzle and it is supposed to show SOFTWARESENI. Can anybody give me an idea to fix this?

```
$string = "
S Q X C P R T M
R O M S P H P D E V C I
X N F P L Z M H R K N J
P D S T X R N D G E B Y
J Z D G W C W E S X
M B S C N A P E Q
Y Z D G Q V R D S";

$string_to_array = explode("\n", $string);
$i = 0;
foreach ($string_to_array as $key => $value) {
    $per_string = explode(" ", $value);
    $hasil[] = $per_string[$i]; 
    $i++;
}
```

Here's my result.

```
    [0] => S
    [1] => O
    [2] => F
    [3] => T
    [4] => W
    [5] => A
    [6] => R
```

The output should be SOFTWARESENI.

Comment: When you say in a pattern like V , do you mean like a word search puzzle. Follow from S to O to F etc, you hit the bottom and you want to come back up A-R-E etc

Comment: So, what's the correct title for this ?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe it is a 'word search grid' . By the way I probably broke it with my edit, tidy up the grid to see the letters better, but I've added lots of spaces... oops - I'll have a think about it, like this sort of thing

Comment: I tried to make it better now, can you help me to fix my code ?

Comment: Ok, couple more questions. Is the grid always the same size, or could it be bigger / smaller. Are you always looking for the V or could that be different in the future. I think to start turn your first array into a grid (multi dimen array) grid[][] may help visualise the problem

Comment: The grid always have the same size and the pattern always like "V".

Comment: Good, you also have a different number of letters in each line of the grid, is this part of the problem, could the empty spaces be filled with any letter to make a full grid?

Comment: Actually every grid has a different number of a letter (Apologize for my last comment if make this confuse). But the alphabets always be the same and the pattern always like V. I need the code just for this case (Not Dynamic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop it once downwards and once upwards and keep track if we hit a "wall" by comparing the $col and the count of item in that row.

```
// Preperations
$arr = explode("\n", $string);
foreach($arr as &$val){
    $val = explode(" ", $val);
}

// start at:
$col=0;

for($row=0; $row<count($arr); $row++){
    if($col >= count($arr[$row])) break; // stop if we reach the end
    $word[] = $arr[$row][$col];
    $col++;
}

// loop rows backwards
for($row=$row-2; $row>0; $row--){
    if($col >= count($arr[$row])) break; // stop if we reach the end
    $word[] = $arr[$row][$col];
    $col++;
}

var_dump($word);
```

output:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "S"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "O"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "F"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "T"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "W"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "R"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "E"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "S"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "E"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "N"
  [11]=>
  string(1) "I"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/IJg9d

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this with using one loop

```
$string_to_array = explode("\n", $string);
$length  = count($string_to_array); // count number of element in array

$j = 0;

// loop twice through $string_to_array once forward and once backward
for($k=0;$k<(($length-1)*2);$k++){

    // explode each element of $string_to_array by index
    $per_string = explode(" ", $string_to_array[$j]);

    // check if indexed element exists and add it to result array
    $hasil[] = isset($per_string[$k]) ? $per_string[$k] : ''; 

    // check if we reached at the end of $string_to_array array
    if($k >= ($length-1)){
        // if we are at end start moving backward
        $j--;
    }else{
       // else move forward
        $j++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($hasil);
echo "</pre>";
```

outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => S
    [1] => O
    [2] => F
    [3] => T
    [4] => W
    [5] => A
    [6] => R
    [7] => E
    [8] => S
    [9] => E
    [10] => N
    [11] => I
)
```

Comment: It's a very confusing code. You should include some comments to explain what and why